# NSE webscrapping problem on python in EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I've did a webscrapping module on NSE Website with the link https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY

The link will give a json response when accessing via requests, it works fine on local. But on deploying the code to EC2 server the requests are getting blocked.

Is there any workaround to make this work on EC2?

Comment: If the reason it doesn't work is that they block all of AWS's published IP addresses, then not really.

Comment: The link you gave returns no results...

Comment: `url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
   
nifty_text = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"})

underlying_value = nifty_text.json()['records']['underlyingValue']`

On local this works fine

Comment: you can just use API from any brokers, most of them give it you for free. this would solve the problem